# What could cause an intermittent NSInternalInconsistencyException when calling resignFirstResponder?

Tags: ios, ios7

Thanks to Crashlytics, I've had reports of my app crashing upon calling `resignFirstResponder`. The crash is due to an NSInternalInconsistencyException with the message  "We were never set up properly to stream in this document". The crash only appears to occur on iOS7, on both iPhone and iPad. The app is not document-based, so I find the mention of document in the message confusing. Thus far, I've been unable to reproduce the problem either on a device or in the simulator. Unfortunately, Googling for the error message yields no results. The crash always occurs on the main thread and the stack always appears to be:

```
0    CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1    libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 38
2    CoreFoundation  +[NSException raise:format:]
3    Foundation      -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 90
4    UIKit           -[UIDictationTestOps willEndEditingInInputDelegate:] + 138
5    UIKit           +[UIDictationController keyboardWillChangeFromDelegate:toDelegate:] + 136
6    UIKit           -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 206
7    UIKit           -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 784
8    UIKit           -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 136
9    UIKit           -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 250
...
```

What could be causing the problem, and what would be a good avenue to explore to reproduce it?

Comment: I'm seeing the same error. I think the Nuance SDK might be related, are you using this too?

Comment: I'm not. The only third-party code in my app is Crashlytics.

Comment: Can you try to replace resignFirstResponder with [self.view endEditing:YES]; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using UIKeyInput for text entry, I get this error every time I tap the dictation button and then close the keyboard. Still looking for a way to fix it (or a way to just disable dictation), though.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT Yes it is. I was looking for a way to reproduce the crash and this answer gives me that.

Comment: Sorry my bad. The answer looked like a question.